# What if ddr4 Termination is done at last word component

Tags: termination, ddr

Memory Component : MT40A256M16

Controller : Xilinx MPSOC - PS Side

Question :
I have mistakenly provided the DDR4 termination resistances at the first data lane and the layout engineer has completed the routing feeling it as last device.

layout was done properly for address lines, driver->comp1->comp2->comp3->comp4->vtt termination

but the data bus is connected in reverse fashion as shown in figure

[image]

does it affect my ddr4 performance ?

logically i dont feel anything has gone bad,

but is it compulsory that when we say last device "it is the device carrying last DQ lane of 64bits of data ?"

Answer (score 1):

As long as the termination resistors are placed at the locations recommended by the memory chip manufacturer you should be good.

1. Any series terminations should be placed close to the driver chip.
2. Any VTT type terminations should be placed at the end of the signal trace lines.
3. Any differential signal terminations are generally placed between the two signals of the differential pair at the extremity of the pair.

Keep in mind that it is the circuit signalling topology that is important to maintain signal integrity. The order of chips in the bussing is not material to the the signal integrity.